# Why does $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] have a value of "127.0.0.1" in local environment?

Tags: php

Shouldn't the value match the IP of the computer that's requesting the script regardless of the fact that it's the same computer that's hosting the script?

Comment: *"That's when I run PHP locally."* totally answers your own question. No?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Please edit in the URL you're accessing as well, or a facsimile of it, and possibly some more information. As it stands now the question is of very low quality, and risk being closed as such.

Comment: If you feel that the question adds no value then go ahead and close it. I got the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Emanuil: Only if you are unaware what `127.0.0.1` is, and that is something so far-fetched that I did not assume it.

Comment: Far fetched != impossible. Once the OP stated he doesn't know, it doesn't matter how far fetched it sounds even if it's coming from a high reputation user.

Comment: @Tomalak, I was aware that `127.0.0.1` is the IP of the local server. What I was not aware of is why it is also the address of the client.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because when you run PHP locally every request you make will come from your machine, which happens to have a remote (or in this case, local) address of... wait for it.... 127.0.0.1 (== localhost).

**Elaboration:** Let's assume for a second you have no internet connection, nothing at all, no WiFi, no cable. The local connection would still work. Why? because it would be **stupid** to require internet connection for ***local affairs***. Instead, the connection comes from the **server itself** which means, you will see `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as the remote address, because that's the remote address of the server, relatively to the server.

Comment: Did you ever watch "How I met your mother"? :p

Comment: That's the thing. My machine has a remote address. Why do I get the local "127.0.0.1" instead of it?

Comment: What do you mean by "has a remote address"? Unless you've borked your network setup, your machine *also* has 127.0.0.1 as an address, and this is used as the source address.

Comment: I mean that it has a regular address that looks something like 95.87...

Comment: Still... 127.0.0.1 is obviously the one used.

Comment: Like Layke explained, when you connect locally the connection stays "inside" the computer. It doesn't go through the public internet. `$_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ]` gives the address where the connection is coming from, not the public IP address of the connecting computer.

Comment: @Lasse, I know that. The question is why is that so?

Comment: @Emanuil I'll edit the answer to explain better.

Comment: Please note that `http://95.87...` would've reported `95.87...` as the source address, so *local* is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that you're talking to 127.0.0.1.

When talking to a network device (local machine or otherwise), packets has to have a source address, and an address is picked that *will be available in the network you're communicating over*.

So the source address used depends on the target address being communicated with.

Since the server is reporting that you're coming *from* 127.0.0.1, you will have to be talking *to* 127.0.0.1, because that's the only target address where that source address would've been picked.

If you had talked to your machine using its IPv6 local address (`::1`), then you would've seen `::1` reported as the source address as well.

However, in order to see the `95.87...` address, you need to be talking *to* that address as well.

You can try that by simply replacing the hostname or localhost or whatever you wrote in the URL with `95.87...` for the hostname part, and it should report that you're also coming from that address.

My guess is that you're doing `http://machinename`, which is resolving to `127.0.0.1`, and thus the `127.0.0.1` address was picked as the source address as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is a local connection.

The connection is being made locally. You local IP address for your **localhost** is 127.0.0.1.

No connections are being made through any other network other than your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

because localhost === 127.0.0.1